# Freeswitch telcentris

Tags: freeswitch

I've been trying to configure FreeSWITCH with telcentris but not working.
FreeSWITCH Currently it works perfectly with other providers.

I tried using the XML configuration that is in the official website (here the link: http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Provider_Configuration:_Telcentris) but nothing.  The only thing that changes in my xml is the user and the ip access and that's what I do. Too put the public context.

I created a lua script that is with the puebas I'm doing, and this is the error that throws me for FreeSWITCH console:
12.19.2012 13:14:58.619723 [NOTICE] switch_cpp.cpp: 1227 TELCENTRIS
12.19.2012 13:14:58.619723 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c: 930 New Channel sofia/external/2590573122223333 [80d4568f-2451-4f72-8de2-65b471a80e20]
12.19.2012 13:14:58.779729 [NOTICE] sofia.c: 6258 Hangup sofia/external/2590573122222222 [CS_CONSUME_MEDIA] [NORMAL_TEMPORARY_FAILURE]
12.19.2012 13:14:58.779729 [NOTICE] switch_cpp.cpp: 1227 *********** Caller: NORMAL_TEMPORARY_FAILURE - Try: 1 ***********
12.19.2012 13:14:58.779729 [NOTICE] switch_cpp.cpp: 1227 REQUESTED

If someone used FreeSWITCH with telcentris, or can tell me what could be the possible failure or error, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be to run `tcpdump` or `wireshark` and collect the whole SIP and RTP traffic for that destination. Then it will be more clear what's going on.

Comment: Hello Stanislav,

Thanks for your time. I was using tcpdump and found that when making the call me request appears on the console tcpdump as follows: "503 No Circuit Available".
I was reviewing the page FreeSWITCH (http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Hangup_causes) and there I could not find the error.

Maybe you know what the problem is and how to get to your solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: in which direction is the call and who is sending the 503 message?

Comment: From my FreeSWITCH made ​​the request to the server telcentris. Through reading tcpdump port 5060 which is what I have configured as external sip port shows me the error 503 No Circuit Available.
Here's the tcpdump output captured:    66.74.90.114.5060 > 78.126.57.97.5060: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 333
C.)......UC.SIP/2.0 503 No Circuit Available
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 78.126.57.97;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK5m3v85Uj2ZjHQ
To: <sip:2570573101231234@66.74.90.114>;tag=sansay584164371rdb27378
From: "" <sip:user@66.74.90.114;transport=udp>;tag=2UZ5cF3NB1jXa

Comment: it will be easier if you upload the full packet capture somewhere and notify me via email, as I don't get notifications from stackexchange. My email address is easy to google out